# Bootstrap-3-Typeahead afterSelect Get ID

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using Bootstrap-3-Typeahead [here](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) for my autocomplete from mysql.
I need to get item_code from selected item_name afterSelect with something like

```
$('#item_code').val(this.item_code);
```

unfortunately not working.

My Json output:

[{"item_code":"1","item_name":"A"},{"item_code":"2","item_name":"B"}]

here's my code, please advise

```
$('input.item_name').typeahead({
                minLength: 3,
                source: function (query, process) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'function/load-item.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: 'query=' + query,
                        success: function(data) {
                            var newData = [];
                            $.each(data, function(){
                                newData.push(this.item_name);
                                });
                            return process(newData);
                            }
                    });
                },
                afterSelect: function(){
                    $('#item_code').val( ... ... ... ... );
                }
            });
```

My php code

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('../include/connect.php');

$query = 'SELECT item_code,item_name FROM master_item';
if(isset($_POST['query'])){
$query .= ' WHERE item_name LIKE "%'.$_POST['query'].'%"';
}

$return = array();
if($result = $conn->query($query)){
    // fetch array
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $return[] = $row;
    }

    // free result set
    $result->close();
    // close connection
    $conn->close();

    $json = json_encode($return);
    print_r($json);
}
```

?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Using `typeahead:selected` instead of `afterSelect` it returns the whole object where you can get your required value i.e.  `.item_code` . I have created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agrg3xhj/35/) , you can see the working example there.

```
$('.typeahead').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
    console.log(datum);
    $('#item_code').val(datum.item_code);
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply mate. it perfectly works with your example. but i need to use a remote data from php. can you help me? I'm trying to adapt this example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/UkB7u/) but no luck. Please advise, thank you

Comment: I have updated the fiddle that you provided, it works here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/UkB7u/1339/

Comment: hey mate, i need your help again. after copying your code and changing the url to mine above, the typeahead always shown 5 first row, and filter not working. please help again, thanks before

Comment: Can you provide me the code? I mean the one that's not working.

Comment: I change the url into my url : function/load-item.php. as i wrote above on my question.

Comment: What problem you are facing? Can you go to your browser console and tell me if there is any error shown there?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103850/discussion-between-geekowls-and-vincmeister).

Answer (score 7):

This is for the benefit of those who might have the same problem in the near future.
**Below is another simple approach to getting the same functionality** using JQuery and [bootstrap-3-typeahead.js or bootstrap-3-typeahead.min.js](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead):

### Example

```js
var url = "codePath/searchCode.php";
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
      return $.get(url, { query: query }, function (data) {
        console.log(data)
     return process(data);
   });
    },
    //this triggers after a value has been selected on the control
    afterSelect: function (data) {
      //print the id to developer tool's console
      console.log(data.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Found a lot of .on('typeahead:selected' .... answers, but nothing worked until this. 
Thank you Deen_Kadir

Comment: @deen_kadir You are the real champ. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

replying on old thread, your code seems to be good, you just missed the argument to the afterSelect callback

```
$('input.item_name').typeahead({
            minLength: 3,
            source: function (query, process) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'function/load-item.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: 'query=' + query,
                    success: function(data) {
                        var newData = [];
                        $.each(data, function(){
                            newData.push(this.item_name);
                            });
                        return process(newData);
                        }
                });
            },
            afterSelect: function(args){
                $('#item_code').val(args.item_code );
            }
        });
```